# Query records from specific years?

Tags: soql, query

```
Public class Demo{
    Acc=[Select id,name from account where id=;]
}
```

I want to display particular time(2004 to 2008) records from database 
which query is used in this?

Comment: I tried to edit your question to be more clear, but what is it exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Check this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm. Combination of NEXT_N_YEARS:n and LAST_N_YEARS:n ?

Comment: i want display particular records in total data base for example my database is full of records till 2010 .but i want display 2011 to 2015 record only .so which query is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious way to do this in code is to compare to variables:

```
Public class Demo{
    DateTime beg = DateTime.newInstance(2004, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             en = DateTime.newInstance(2008, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Account Acc=[Select id,name from account 
                    where CreatedDate >= :beg and CreatedDate <= :en]; 
}
```

This method makes it relatively simple to change which dates you actually want to compare to (just change the variables and the soql stays the same).

If you need to use a literal soql query, dates are denoted with ISO formatting (also note the lack of single quotes):

```
Select id,name from account where CreatedDate >= 2004-01-01T00:00:00Z and CreatedDate <= 2008-12-31T00:00:00Z
```

As noted by SL man in comments, while your stated case doesn't need it you can also use [relative date literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) like `LAST_N_YEARS:n`.

Answer (score 5):

At time of writing, your question is not at all clear. However, I think what you're looking for is one of the SOQL Date Literals outlined in [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) (also linked in one of the comments on your question).

For querying records from 2004-2008, you would use `LAST_N_YEARS:n` (since both of those years are in the past).

An example query, based on pulling records created during those years would be

```
[SELECT Id 
 FROM Account 
 WHERE CreatedDate >= LAST_N_YEARS:13 AND CreatedDate <= LAST_N_YEARS:9]
```

Of course, the window for this query would shift every year (in 2018, this would fetch records created between 2005 and 2009).

If you always want to pull records from the 2004-2008 window, using `CALENDAR_YEAR()`, one of the [SOQL Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) , would be more appropriate.

An example of that would look like this

```
[SELECT Id 
 FROM Account 
 WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) >= 2004 AND CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) <= 2008]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use CALENDAR_YEAR for specific years:

```
Integer[] years = new Integer[] { 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008 };
Account[] records = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) IN :years];
```

Answer (score 0):

HI you can use Calendar_Year like below: -
Select Name, createdDate from Account where Calendar_Year(CreatedDate) >= 2004 AND Calendar_Year(CreatedDate) <= 2008

Hope this ans will help you